# Can I add sample weights to the training dataset?

Tags: cntk

Is it possible to add to the configuration (eg, SGD block) sample weights? Where each training example is assigned a weight?

In many cases, a simple 1/N (where N is the total number of samples in the training dataset) is good enough, but in others, I would like the network to put extra "emphasis" in certain examples. Can this be done in CNTK?

Thanks,

Pedro

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done. If your task is binary classification you can use WeightedLogistic (label, probability, weight).

Typically weight will be an Input() which you can hook up to a stream in your data (assuming you are using CNTKTextFormatReader you can just have a |weight stream).

It can also be done for tasks other than binary classification with a little more effort.